# Codeigniter - cannot load files in production server

Tags: codeigniter, production-environment

I have problem that cannot load any css, js, images, etc in production server.

Error `resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

This is the my folder tree

```
public_html/
    application/
    assets/
    ...
```

I'm using `base_url()` when try to load any file in `assets` directory,

example: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />`

I have no idea why i can't load such as those files.
Can anyone please help me with this issue?

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: may you post what url you get after run this on browser ..? you can check url by Source code

Comment: @RishiShrivastava somepage.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css. According to my folder tree, this should be no error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you autoload the url helper? In application/config/autoload.php

Comment: @lloistborn is your internal page is running well if no then it's may be .htaccess issue .

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yes i have loaded them.

Comment: @RishiShrivastava Yes, it is running well. I also think this must be the .htaccess issue. Check out my .htaccess, i updated my question above.

Comment: @lloistborn please replace htacess  which i write in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please use this .htacess

Answer (score 0):

did u edit the application/config/config.php base_url? 

or

i used it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

or i used it the wrong way?

Comment: i'm not sure, but i did the right rules. It has no problem in local server. @Noobie

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the file rights on server ?? It should be executable xrw